# Firefox doesn’t detect my Nvidia GPU

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, firefox, nvidia-optimus

I have an Optimus laptop with an Intel iGPU and an Nvidia dGPU, and just noticed that when using the Nvidia GPU (activated with `prime-select nvidia`), WebGL-based games run software-rendered on the Firefox browser, with the noticeable performance problems one can imagine.

The Nvidia driver is properly loaded, I can play “standard” (i.e. non-browser) games correctly, but everything inside Firefox is software-rendered. `about:support` indeed shows two GPUs, GPU1 being *llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)*, and GPU2, marked inactive, being my Intel dGPU (vendor/device being 0x8086/0x9bc4).

When I use the Intel GPU only (`prime-select intel`), hardware acceleration works properly for WebGL games on Firefox.

I use the latest 535 Nvidia driver, with X11, not Wayland, on 23.04 (lunar).

Any suggestions on what I should do to have Firefox detect my Nvidia GPU as it does with Intel Graphics ?